# Creating a fade effect between two images with their own classes

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to create a fade effect between two logos. They swap but it doesn't look great. Can anyone advise me of the best way to do this?

Here is my code:

```css
.header.affix .logo-second {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.header.affix .logo-first{
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a data-scroll href="#home" id="brand" class="navbar-brand" style="padding-right: 100px;">
  <!--
       The URLs in the src attributes below have been replace by data: URLs
       for demostration purposes
  -->
  <img src='data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="background: red"/>' class="logo-first" alt="">
  <img src='data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="background: green"/>' class="logo-second" style="width: 70%; padding-top: 15px;">
</a>
```

Comment: <a data-scroll href="#home" id="brand" class="navbar-brand" style="padding-right: 100px;"><img src="images/logow.png" class="logo-first" alt=""><img src="images/logow2.png" class="logo-second" style="width: 70%; padding-top: 15px;"></a>

Comment: How are you triggering the transition?

Comment: when the header scrolls it changes from .header to .header-affix - so i added this the css which hid logo-first and replaced it with logo-second

Comment: here is the site http://ptdtest.website/home2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with the `display:none;` property. It is does not support animation. The best way to go about this would be to use `opacity` instead.

See below:

```
.header.affix .logo-second {
  opacity:1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.header.affix .logo-first{
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

---edit

If the logo's are supposed to be on top of each other, you want to consider dropping them both into a div / wrapper and mess around with positions.

---edit 2

Just to add some clarification (mentioned in comments) remember to remove the `display:none / block` properties as changing the opacity of an element will not affect it's display state.

Comment: If you're still having problems, create a jsfiddle post the link here :)

Comment: Thank you! the fade is working for the first logo but now the second logo isnt displaying. Would you mind having a quick look at the site

Comment: ptdtest.website/home2.html

Comment: Cool - it's because you are still using the `display` properties. If you add `.header.affix .logo-second { display: block;}` to your stylesheet it will fix the problem. Remember, opacity and display are two different properties, You can adjust the opacity, but if it is still set to `display:none;` it won't show in any case :) alternatively, remove the `display:none;` from `.logo-second` and add `.logo-second {opacity: 0;}` instead.

Comment: amazing! thank you so much, the only issue is it now has knocked logo-second out of place. But that should be easily sorted!

Comment: I'm glad to have help. You can always go for a quick fix with logo by giving it a `position:relative;` and a `bottom:20px;` Please remember to mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: would this be added to both classes in my .css?

Comment: im still having the issue that the images are not on top of each other at the moment. I have tried putting them inside different divs and editing that way but it doesnt seem to be having any beneficial effect

Comment: I've had a look at what you currently have - add this: `.navbar-brand > img {
  position: absolute;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `display` is not a transitionable property. Try using `opacity` instead to get a fade effect. If you want to wait for the first one to fade out before fading in the second one then just play around with the `transition-duration` property.

Side note: best to avoid using the `all` `transition-property` whenever possible. Also, you probably don't need all those prefixed; only one browser currently needs prefixes for the `transition` properties. Check [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) for more info on which browsers you might need to prefix for.

```
.header .logo-first,.header .logo-second{
    transition:opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
.header.affix .logo-first,.header .logo-second{
    opacity:0;
}
.header.affix .logo-second{
    opacity:1;
}
```